# Delete a row in msaccess

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have to delete a records, but getting error `Specify the table containing the records you want to delete.`

```
oleDbCmd.CommandText = "DELETE call_samp FROM call_samp INNER JOIN prod_mas ON prod_mas.id=call_samp.prod_id WHERE call_samp.id=@id;";
oleDbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 495);
oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And tried with

```
 DELETE  call_samp.*
    FROM  call_samp
    INNER JOIN prod_mas ON prod_mas.id=call_samp.prod_id WHERE call_samp.id=495;
```

giving error couldnt delete from specific rows.

Comment: Just a quick look: `DELETE FROM table_name` or `DELETE * FROM table_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
oleDbCmd.CommandText = "DELETE call_samp FROM call_samp INNER JOIN prod_mas ON prod_mas.id=call_samp.prod_id WHERE call_samp.id=@id;";
    oleDbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 495);
    oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an issue with your SQL code. There is no need to specify the column or columns when using the delete command as you are deleting a whole row.

Just go with:

```
    DELETE FROM call_samp INNER JOIN prod_mas ON prod_mas.id=call_samp.prod_id WHERE call_samp.id=@id;
```

for the SQL code.